# HTML page, save it self

Tags: javascript, html, server

Here is my code that I have a question about.

```
if (countdown_seconds == 172) {
                var table = document.getElementById("update");
                var row = table.insertRow(0);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                var dice = localStorage.getItem("dice");
                var OE = localStorage.getItem("OE");
                var LH = localStorage.getItem("LH");
                cell1.innerHTML = clock_info.mm + "," + clock_info.dd;
                cell2.innerHTML = pr + "count";
                cell3.innerHTML = dice;
                cell4.innerHTML = OE;
                cell5.innerHTML = LH;
```

I have used a table.insertRow and it does work. But here is my question, I like to keep this table (and it is going to be random) even if the page refresh. 
In addition I have used localstorge but it wasn't working because I wanted to keep adding  and until I have 100 .

Is there anyway I can save HTML whenever it changes the code on the server side? (automatically)

Comment: Why didn't localstorage work? I don't understand that part. Unless you implement a login system and store the data server side, localstorage is probably your best bet.

Comment: _"Is there anyway I can save HTML whenever it changes the code on the server side? (automatically)"_ How is `HTML` `document` aware that the code changed at server?

Comment: @Carcigenicate it's likely that the OP tried to the it to store HTML.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Oh. You'd probably want to convert it to JSON first. I can see storing raw html being brittle af.

Comment: @Carcigenicate `HTML` can be stored as a string

Comment: Thank you for all the reply. I trying make a dice game.. Dice is roll every 3 min. I just want to show a result of the dice. I mean all the dice result as well as previous dice result. I want to update dice result every 3 min And I dont know how... Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @Andrew The text of the Question does not inquire about the logic of the application, but rather, what technologies available at browser can achieve requirement. There are a number of possible approaches which could be used to get data from server every given duration; including the approaches at Answer, or for example utilizing `ServiceWorker`. If your current logic does not return expected result as to rendering dice, that is a different question.

Comment: that localStorge is to get dice result I can only save one result. I like to save that result to my html as <tr> and remove from localStorge and store it new value when dice roll and on and on.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be at least two inquiries at Question, possibly three

1. Maintain `countdown_seconds` if `document` reloads
2. Create `localStorage` key and value if they do not exist at `localStorage` or save changes to existing `localStorage` when changes to code are made server side

---

1. You can use approaches at 
   [Global Variable usage on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload/30144363?s=2|1.3579#30144363) to address saving reference to global variable if or when page is reloaded
2. Utilize `EventSource` [how to send xmlhttprequest continuously in webworker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512572/how-to-send-xmlhttprequest-continuously-in-webworker/42513099#42513099) to receive a continuous stream of data from server